# fetch API doesn't return value in promise.all

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I changed one api call from XMLHttpRequest to fetch and the promise.all I had in code stopped working. would appreciate any help. Thank you

Here is the original api call with XMLHttpRequest and the promise.all I had from this call and another api call:

```
const configApiPromise = token => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "/api/econfig", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    xhttp.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300 && this.readyState == 4) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhttp.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhttp.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhttp.statusText
      });
    };
    xhttp.send();
  });
}

Promise.all([configApiPromise(token), simApiPromise(token)]);
```

Here is the same api call which I wrote with fetch and the promise.all with the other api call:

```
const configApiFetch = token => {
  var authHeader = new Headers();
  authHeader.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

  var myInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: authHeader,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
  };

  var myRequest = new Request('/api/econfig', myInit);

  return fetch(myRequest)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(function (data) {
      return data; // here in debugger I see it returns data but in promise.all it returns undefined
    });
}

Promise.all([configApiFetch(token), simApiPromise(token)]);
```

The first code works fine and the values are returned from promise whereas with the second one (fetch call), the value after promise.all() is undefined although when inspecting the  configApiFetch it returns data. Which part I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help

also here two functions I used:

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {
    var error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}
```

Here is the complete code where promise.all is called :

```
window.accessToken = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   //do some stuff here
                     resolve(token)
                }
            });
       }).then(token => {
           Promise.all([configApiPromise(token), simApiPromise(token)]);
```

and on another place I am waiting for result of this promise which returns undefined for fetch api call :

```
const response = await (window as any).accessToken; // whole response is undefinded
const configresponse = JSON.parse(response[0]); 
const simResponse = JSON.parse(response[1]);
```

Comment: Why `mode: 'cors',`?

Comment: The code looks like it should work; also you're saying that the promise resolves with the correct value in the debugger. This would suggest that in your actual code you probably forgot a `return` somewhere, like the one in front of `fetch(…).then(…)`. Also please post the code you use to inspect the value "*after promise.all()*".

Comment: Are you able to share what you get with a ```.then``` call after ```Promis.all``` something like: ```Promise.all([configApiFetch(token), simApiPromise(token)]).then((results) => console.log(results));```

Comment: the cors wasn't intentional, I updated the code

Comment: What **exactly** did your `Promise.all` code look like before you moved to `fetch`? This problem really doesn't look like it's got anything to do with the implementation of `configApiPromise`

Comment: it was like this : Promise.all([configApiPromise(token), simApiPromise(token)]);

Comment: How did you use it? Has that changed at all between implementations? Also, you have a missing closing brace and parenthesis after `.then(token => { Promise.all(...)`

Comment: More syntax problems... you have an extra `}` and `});` after `resolve(token)`. How can you expect help if your code is such a mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're missing a `return` in there:

```
window.accessToken = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //do some stuff here {
       resolve(token)
    // }
}).then(token => {
    return Promise.all([configApiPromise(token), simApiPromise(token)]);
//  ^^^^^^
});
```

It should not matter how your `configApiPromise` function is implemented for that.

Comment: actually I had return but deleted when I was testing different things. adding back return. the whole response is undefined in this piece: const response = await (window as any).accessToken;
    const configresponse = JSON.parse(response[0]); // here it throws exception that response[0] is undefinded
   const simResponse = JSON.parse(response[1]); //

Comment: @AlreadyLost Then clearly you did not post the complete code. `response` can't be `undefined` when it comes from `Promise.all`, which always fulfills with an array.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of please debug my code questions are difficult to answer especially when you have a `return` statement missing in the question that you say isn't missing in the actual code.

Maybe you're messing with the global value called `accessToken` you can make sure it's set:

```
window.accessToken = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  //do some stuff here
  resolve(token)
}).then(token => {
  //return missing here
  return Promise.all([configApiPromise(token), simApiPromise(token)]);
}).then(
  results=>{
    console.log("results are:",JSON.stringify(results,undefined,2));
    //returning results again
    return results;
  }
).catch(
  err=>console.warn("Something went wrong:",err)
);
```

Could you please log the data before returning as well?

```
.then(function (data) {
  console.log("returning data in configApiFetch:",JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2));
  return data; // here in debugger I see it returns data but in promise.all it returns undefined
});
```